# Wrong path to font in MiniCssExtractPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, bundler

I have a 404 error because the font path is wrong. Now is `dist/font` , but page try find it at `dist/style/font` .

This is my config jsfiddle.net/sicely/z8g5sr9e

I am import fonts in this way

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
    src: url(../assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf) format("truetype")
}
```

If I put all my bundle in the root, all work fine

Comment: Can you create a little github repo (not the whole project) in order to see what is wrong?

Comment: @Legends problem solved, answer below if you're interested. Thank you for your help. You can create an answer like me, and I accept it. Because I have a delay 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|woff)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:6].[ext]',
                    publicPath: '../',
                },
            },
        }
```

Problem solved if I add a publicPath to file-loader options

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The root cause was in webpack `output.publicPath`. It was absolute `"assets/"`. Changing it to relative "/assets/" fixed problem with MiniCssExtractPlugin and fonts urls. Author`s solution also solves the problem but it is rather workaround. You should avoid absolute publicPaths.